# How to read an excel file in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am newbie to Python.
Basically, I want to write a program to read column `D` & `E` from an excel file, and calculate the total `Incoming` and `Outgoing` duration.

Which Python module is used to read excel files and how to process data inside it?

**Excel file:**

```
D            E
Incoming    18
Outgoing    99
Incoming    20
Outgoing    59
Incoming    30
Incoming    40
```

Comment: You can check [xlrd](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd) or [openpyxl](https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl) for reading `.xls` or `.xlsx` files in Python. Or, you can convert your excel workbook to `.csv` file and read it using Python's [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) or combine `open()` and `str.split()`.

Comment: I tried numpy but i was able to read data bot unable to process data inside it. but now it working with xlrd ..Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

there are a couple of options depending on the version of excel you are using.
openpyxl - used for reading Excel 2010 files (ie: .xlsx)
xlrd - used for reading older Excel files (ie: .xls)

I have only used xlrd, which you could do something like the below
** Note ** code not tested

```
import xlrd


current_row = 0
sheet_num = 1
input_total = 0
output_total = 0

# path to the file you want to extract data from
src = r'c:\temp\excel sheet.xls'

book = xlrd.open_workbook(src)

# select the sheet where the data resides
work_sheet = book.sheet_by_index(sheet_num)

# get the total number of rows
num_rows = work_sheet.nrows - 1

while current_row < num_rows:
    row_header = work_sheet.cell_value(current_row, 4)

    if row_header == 'output':
        output_total += work_sheet.cell_value(current_row, 5)
    elif row_header == 'input':
        input_total += work_sheet.cell_value(current_row, 5)

print output_total
print input_total
```

Comment: Moura Thanks for the extended help it really helped me to achieve my task :)

Answer (score 2):

It seems like simply using Excel's [`=SUMIF()`](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/SUMIF-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b) function would be sufficient.  However, you're asking for a Python solution, so here's a Python solution!

Pandas is a library that provides a DataFrame data structure very similar to an Excel spreadsheet.  It provides a `read_excel()` function, whose documentation you can find [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html).  Once you have a DataFrame, you could do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
table = pd.read_excel('path-to-spreadsheet.xlsx')
incoming_sum = table.E[table.D == 'Incoming'].sum()
outgoing_sum = table.E[table.D == 'Outgoing'].sum()
```

You can get Pandas for Python on Windows, but it's a bit difficult.  The easiest way is a Scientific Python distribution for Windows, like [Anaconda](https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/).  On Linux, installing `pandas` is simple as `sudo pip install pandas`.

Comment: Thanks for the your response.. but I tried with xlrd and its working now.

Answer (score 1):

**Using [xlrd 0.9.3](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd) in Python 3.4.1:**

It puts all values from row `D` and `E` in two separate `list`.

It then combines each parallel elements of these lists (simply elements with same index) to a tuple using `zip()`.

Then, these generated tuples are combined to a `list`. Using `sum()` and list comprehension, `incoming_sum` and `outgoing_sum` are calculated.

```
import xlrd

with xlrd.open_workbook('z.xlsx') as book:

    # 0 corresponds for 1st worksheet, usually named 'Book1'
    sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)

    # gets col D values
    D = [ D for D in sheet.col_values(3) ]

    # gets col E values
    E = [ E for E in sheet.col_values(4) ]

    # combines D and E elements to tuples, combines tuples to list
    # ex. [ ('Incoming', 18), ('Outgoing', 99), ... ]
    data = list( zip(D, E) )

    # gets sum
    incoming_sum = sum( tup[1] for tup in data if tup[0] == 'Incoming' )
    outgoing_sum = sum( tup[1] for tup in data if tup[0] == 'Outgoing' )

    print('Total incoming:', incoming_sum)
    print('Total outgoing:', outgoing_sum)
```

***Output:***

```
Total incoming: 108.0
Total outgoing: 158.0
```

**To install [xlrd](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd): (Windows)**

1. **Download** here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd
2. **Extract** to any directory, then **change** `cmd`'s **current directory** ( `chdir` ) to the directory where you extracted, **then type in cmd** `python setup.py install`

   - Take note that you will extract `xlrd-0.9.3.tar.gz` **two times**, first to remove `.gz`, second to remove `.tar`.
   - The extracted directory (where you will change your cmd's current directory) will look like this:[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response it was really helpful..since I am new your sample program helped me lot. one more thing could you suggest me some best sources to learn network programming in python..